# Can we use 3.3 to 5 voltage logic level converter to drive a sensor?

Tags: voltage, step-up

I have a question that can we use **3.3V to 5V voltage logic level converter** to drive a sensor which works on 5V as input voltage? Can we supply that 5V as input voltage to sensor or is there any ready-made module which steps up 3.3V voltage to 5V?
Your precious answers will be highly appreciated.
[image]

Comment: Powering something and sending/receiving communication signals to it are two different things. A step-up converter/regulator is used for power and a logic level converter is for communication signals, not for powering.. It is not clear which scenario you are asking for.

Comment: @DKNguyen, thanks for your reply, I was a bit confused that's why I asked a weird question. So in my case voltage booster will be good choice not logic level converter right ?

Comment: I don't know because I still don't know for sure which it is you are asking about. But it is whatever I said it is.

Comment: **Exactly which converter???**  You don't say, but beware that many only provide extremely limited signal current on the high side.

Comment: Like the one from Spark fun I added in my post, which steps down 5V signals to 3.3V and steps up 3.3V to 5V.

Comment: That's not going to work.  It is for microamp signals, not supplies.

Comment: **A 3.3V(LV) to 5V(HV) logic level translator does not generate 5V power from 3.3V power**; it only uses a 3.3V logic signal (LV1) to control an already-existing higher voltage 5V(HV) power supply, which was provided to the level translator from somewhere else. The HV and LV pins are the power supply inputs. The sensor needs to be powered by whatever 5V(HV) supply you are using to power your 3.3V to 5V level translator.

Comment: Got it thank you

Answer (score 1):

You probably could, since sensors normally don't take much current, but where would 5V for the translator come from? The translator has usually two power inputs, for the 3.3V side and for the 5V side, and you power them somehow with 3.3V and 5V respectively.

There is plenty of boost converters, discrete and modules, isolated and not isolated. For all sorts of current. It would be easier to guide you with more data about what you are doing.

Comment: thank you so much for your reply, I am using a small LiDAR sensor, it average current is 70mA and peak current is 150mA. So my question is can I use that stepped up signal from logic level converter (that converts the level from 3.3 to 5V) as input voltage source to drive the sensor? Can you please tell me what is maximum current that we can get through 5V communication signal ?

Comment: My scenario is that I have a system with only 3.3V as supply voltage, but my sensor needs 5V input voltage (not communication signal but supply voltage) in order to improve the accuracy. waiting for your precious comments

Comment: @Ibrahim You need a step up converter to boost the 3.3V supply voltage to 5V. Communication signals transmit minimal current though so it's not a concern most of the time. They communicate with voltage and almost zero current.

Comment: Many converters cannot provide anything near 70 mA, for example one of the more common designs is limited to microamps before the voltage sags below what you started with, because it depends on a 10K pullup resistor.

Comment: Ibrahim, more clearly, no, you need a boost convert. The simplest for you - look for an isolated 3.3V to 5V converter.